# Python rearrange list based on another list

Tags: python, list

I want to rearrange a list based on another list which have common elements between them.

```
my list = ['q','s','b','f','l','c','x','a']
base_list = ['z','a','b','c']
```

Above lists have common 'a','b' and 'c' as common elements.the expected outcome for is as below

```
my_result = ['a','b','c','q','s','f','l','x']
```

Thanks in Advance
Sky

Comment: What is the logic and what did you try?

Comment: It's probably too late to say this but StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166). Update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: If you can use outside libraries the panda's library it is really useful for sorting and modifying list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = ['q','s','b','f','l','c','x','a']
base_list = ['z','a','b','c']

res1=[x for x in base_list if x in my_list] # common elements
res2=[x for x in my_list if x not in res1] # 
res3=res1+res2
```

Output :

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'q', 's', 'f', 'l', 'x']
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if there are repetitions in `my_list`, since it only iterates over `base_list` first. It removes the duplicates in the result. So `my_list = ['q','s','b','b','f','l','c','x','a']` should result in `['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'q', 's', 'f', 'l', 'x']` but the 2nd `b` gets skipped using the method in this answer. Use the method in [@gold_cy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70507609/1431750) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom key for `sorted` as shown in this [document](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html). Set the value arbitrarily high for the letters that don't appear in the `base_list` so they end up in the back. Since `sorted` is considered [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) those that aren't in the `base_list` will remain untouched in terms of original order.

```
l = ['q','s','b','f','l','c','x','a']
base_list = ['z','a','b','c']

def custom_key(letter):
    try:
        return base_list.index(letter)
    except ValueError:
        return 1_000

sorted(l, key=custom_key)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'q', 's', 'f', 'l', 'x']
```

Answer (score 0):

A (probably non optimal) way:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: base_list.index(x) if x in base_list 
                                                     else len(base_list)+1)

['a', 'b', 'c', 'q', 's', 'f', 'l', 'x']
```